# Convert plaintext to perform elgamal encryption

Tags: java, encryption, elgamal

Hi i'm writing a program in java to test a variant of the elgamal encryption, however my problem is not the `encryption/decryption` chain itself, but how to perform the operations on the input given: a text file. I have a text file with some words in it (for example the content can be: `"Hello world, this is a test"`) and i need to perform numeric operations on them like this:

> ciphertext= (message * y) mod p

where `y` and `p` are two `biginteger`. I tried this conversion chain: (reading one string at time):

> String->Hexadecimal->Decimal

Then perform the encrypt operation, and then the inverse:

> Decimal->Hexadecimal->String

<strike>But this doesn't work all the time (i'm currently investigate on this issue).</strike> fixed.

My question is, there is a better way to do this? I was reading about the `byte array`'s but i'm not sure how to use them.

[i can post an example of the encryption/decryption chain if needed]

Comment: "but this doesn't work all the time"- How do we know which time it works and which time it wasn't? Show your code so that we understand where was the problem.

Comment: @rakeb.void i'm currently investigate on this issue but with large prime (>1024bit) it isn't fast to test (keep in mind that even a short word from the plaintext is a pretty big number when converted in integer. Example, the word "hello" is equal to "448378203247"). I don't think my chain of conversions is good but it's the only thing that came to my mind to solve this problem, however my question is still open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BigInteger has a [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28byte[]%29) taking a byte array as argument.

Any String can be converted to a byte array, without loss, using (for example), UTF-8 encoding:

```
byte[] bytes = string.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Combine both, and you have an easy way to transform a String into a BigDecimal.

For the reverse operation, use [BigInteger.toByteArray()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toByteArray%28%29), and then `new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`.

Comment: Thanks, i think this is what i was looking for, and now i'm able to skip the hexadecimal conversion. However, i did some tests and it doesn't work with some special characters like "è" "ò" and similar (my solution with hexadecimal suffers from this problem too). I think it's because of the StandardCharsets UTF_8 but I'm new to this kind of things so i'm not sure. Any ideas to resolve this?

Comment: It does work with accents. If it doesn't, then it probably means that your source files encoding doesn't match with the encoding used to compile the code. Use UTF8 everywhere (`javac -encoding UTF-8`).

Comment: I created a txt file with notepad and i choose the encoding UTF-8 but it doesnt work with char like "è". Then i tried without file, using the input from the user console:
    Scanner user_input = new Scanner( System.in);
    text= user_input.next( );
but this doesn't work too. In the first case the problem can be the way i used to read/write the file, but for the input from console i have no idea why it doesn't work.